# how do i put values from second ngrepeat into $filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

im new to angularJs, im trying to get values from second ngrepeat into $filter with no success

this is the html :

```
<div  ng-repeat="user in  users.results">
<div> 
<span ng-repeat="e in user.markets"  > <a  href="#!"   ><span  id='{{e.id}}'></a> </span> 
</div>

</div>
```

and in angularJs:

```
var fltuser = $filter('filter')($scope.user.markets);
```

thanks

Comment: What filtering are you trying to achieve? With a property e.g. `id`?

Comment: User.markets have json data : price , id

Comment: I got error in console that markets is not defined

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong. 
Try something like this:

```
<div  ng-repeat="user in users.results">
<span ng-repeat="e in user.markets | filter : 'a' "  > 
    <a href="#!"><span id='{{e.id}}'></span> </a> 
</span> 
</div>
```